# skype name detect in vb.net SKYPE4COMLib

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to make skypebot, and im stuck on detectin the message senders name

like im trying to make command like !help admin. and only have people that are on the admin textbox, their names on there to be able to use it, like if he is it gives commands and if not then it just prints something like "no access to this command"

```
    Private Sub skype_MessageStatus(ByVal msg As ChatMessage, ByVal status As TChatMessageStatus)
    Dim Trigger As String = "!"
    Dim BotName As String = "@PandyBot"
    Dim Message As String
    Try

        If status = TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived Or status = TChatMessageStatus.cmsSent Then
            Message = msg.Body
            If Message.StartsWith(Trigger) Then
                Message = Message.Remove(0, 1)
                msg.Chat.SendMessage(BotName & ": " & ParseMessage(Message))
            End If
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Function ParseMessage(ByVal message As String) As String
    Dim msg As String = "Command not regonized!"
    Select Case message
        Case "test"
            msg = "Is working correctly"
        Case "help"
            msg = "use !help user or !help admin"
        Case "help admin"
            If 
                msg = "!poll, !jail, !murder, !ban"
            Else
                msg = " lol1"
            End If
        Case "help user"
            msg = "!test, !time, !date, !credits, secret"
        Case "date"
            msg = "Current Date is: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()
        Case "time"
            msg = "Current Time is: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
            Exit Select
    End Select
    Return msg
End Function
```

thats pretty much ive done.

Comment: It is best to use the [vendor's support forum](http://community.skype.com/t5/English/ct-p/English?profile.language=en) to look for help.